# Query en Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, backend

Soy nuevo en Django y quería saber si hay alguna forma de hacer filtrados de querys con multiples valores de un mismo campo de mi modelo? Follow es mi modelo donde guardo los pk de los usuarios follower y following; la consulta follows me devuelve todos los follows en los que yo figuro como follower para después poder acceder al atributo following. Después hago un lista de los pk de following para filtrar los posts hechos por usuarios con los pk de mi lista de following. Sé que entregar un lista como parametro da error, pero la plasmo para intentar explicar lo que quiero hacer que es filtrar todos los post de los usuarios que sigo. Dejo la vista que lista los posts:

```
class PostsFeedView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
   """Return all posts published by following."""

    template_name = "posts/feed.html"
    ordering = ("-created")
    paginate_by = 30
    context_object_name = "posts"

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        follows = Follow.objects.filter(follower=user.pk)
        following = []
        for follow in follows:
            following.append(follow.following)
        posts = Post.objects.filter(user__id=following)
        return posts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la noche del mismo día que tuve este problema, encontré la solución.

Para filtar un query con multiples valores de un mismo campo, es tan sencillo como pasarle una lista de esos valores. Ejemplo:

```
class PostsFeedView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    """Return all posts published by following."""

    template_name = "posts/feed.html"
    ordering = ("-created")
    paginate_by = 30
    context_object_name = "posts"

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        follows = Follow.objects.filter(follower=user.pk)
        following = [follow.following for follow in follows]
        following.append(user.id)

        # Entrego lista con valores como parametro
        posts = Post.objects.filter(user__id__in=following)
        return posts
```